# Remove method does not work for custom UI widget

Tags: java

I've put together a small UI widget, but the remove button on it does not work. Whenever I click on it nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
public class ComboBoxProblem extends JFrame {
    static JLabel citiesLabel = new JLabel();
    static JList citiesList = new JList();
    static JScrollPane citiesScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    static JButton remove = new JButton();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComboBoxProblem().show();
    }

    public ComboBoxProblem() {
        // create frame
        setTitle("Flight Planner");
        setResizable(false);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints;
        citiesLabel.setText("Destination City");
        gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
        getContentPane().add(citiesLabel, gridConstraints);
        citiesScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
        citiesScrollPane.setViewportView(citiesList);
        gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        getContentPane().add(citiesScrollPane, gridConstraints);

        // Here is my list with my elements, that I want to remove

        final DefaultListModel Model = new DefaultListModel();
        Model.addElement("San Diego");
        Model.addElement("Los Angeles");
        Model.addElement("Orange County");
        Model.addElement("Ontario");
        Model.addElement("Bakersfield");
        Model.addElement("Oakland");
        Model.addElement("Sacramento");
        Model.addElement("San Jose");

        citiesList.setModel(Model);

        final JList list = new JList(Model);

        remove.setText("Remove");
        gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 3;
        getContentPane().add(remove, gridConstraints);

        // Here is my removing method, I don't know, where the problem is
        // and it is showing no error

        remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int sel = list.getSelectedIndex();
                if (sel >= 0) {

                    Model.removeElementAt(sel);
                }
            }
        });

        pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your event firing?

Comment: Also.... are the other two snippets inside your constructor?  It looks like they should be, but that could be an important detail.

Comment: it is showing nothing to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
int sel = list.getSelectedIndex();
```

By this one:

```
int sel = citiesList.getSelectedIndex();
```

list.getSelectedIndex() was always returning -1.

Please use debug in the future in order to get more information about what is going on in your code.